# Representation by a quadratic binary form

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

For $m$ a non-zero integer and discriminant $d=b^2-4ac$ congruent to either 0 or 1 modulo 4, show that m is properly represented by some binary quadratic form $f(x)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ if and only if the congruence $$z^2\equiv d\ (mod\ 4|m|)$$has a solution.

I have proved the forward half, but cannot prove the congruence implies the proper representation.

Comment: What is $\;z\;$ , anyway?

Comment: z is can be any integer, just a place holder to demonstrate that d is a quadratic residue

Comment: Oh...so write so! Write "...iff $\;d\;$ is a quadratic residue modulo $\;m\;$" .

Comment: How did you prove the forward result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$  z^2 = d + 4mt,   $$ then $$ z^2 - 4mt = d, $$ and the binary
$$  \langle m,z,t \rangle  $$ or
$$  g(x,y) = m x^2 + z xy + t y^2  $$
gives
$$  g(1,0) = m $$

Added: note that they are not saying anything about $\gcd(m,z,t).$ The forms that are in (and contribute to $h(d)$) the form class group are primitive, but this problem may produce an imprimitive form. For that matter, they do not prohibit $d$ from being a square, which allows sort of degenerate forms that factor, such as $x^2 - y^2$